# Filter HTML Table with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, filter, html-table

I am creating a comparison table about broadband and wish to add some jQuery UI Sliders to the top of the table that will enable you to filter the data based on Download Usage, Speed etc.

For example if I slide the slider to 20GB only the rows that have a download usage of 20GB and over will be shown. Is this possible?

I would like to add this functionality to sort the table: http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#rangemin

Or if that is not possible then a drop down would be fine. If I have to pull the data in via ajax then that would be fine too.

Here is my code for the table with 1 row.

```
<table>

<thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="bestseller"></th>
        <th class="device"></th>
        <th class="logo"></th>
        <th class="package">Bestsellers</th>
        <th class="speed">Speed</th>
        <th class="data">Data</th>
        <th class="term">Term</th>
        <th class="price">Price</th>
        <th class="button"></th>
    </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>

    <tr>
        <td class="bestseller">1</td><td class="device"><img alt="Dongle" class="dongle" src="images/dongles/three.png"></td>
        <td class="logo"><img alt="Logo" src="images/three.png"></td>
        <td class="package"><div class="name">Three Standard Broadband</div><div class="info">Great deal including a free dongle.</div></td>
        <td class="speed"><div class="upto">up to</div>7.2Mbps</td>
        <td class="data">15GB</td>
        <td class="term">24<div class="months">Month(s)</div></td>
        <td class="price">£15.99</td>
        <td class="button"><div class="deal">See Deal</div></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: It is definitely possible. What have you tried?

Comment: I have tried to implement this http://blog.joshsoftware.com/2011/09/28/filter-js-client-side-search-filtering-using-json-and-jquery/ but couldn't work out how I output the data.

Comment: How big is the table? What table plugin are you using(if any?) what version of jQuery? Do you need to filter using AJAX, or would inline filtering be enough?

Comment: There are multiple tables with about 20 rows, No table plugin is being used, jQuery 1.7 is what Im using. Inline filtering would be enough unless ajax would be easier?

Comment: Inline filtering would be pretty easy.

Comment: Would you be able to give me a example of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/EKpGk/

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Price</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Super Phone</td>
        <td class="price">£15.99</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Wonder Phone</td>
        <td class="price">£25.99</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<br/>

Filter - enter minimum price:

<input type='text' id='filter' />

<button id='btnFilter'>Go</button>
```

Javascript (Requires JQuery)

```
$('#btnFilter').click(function() {

    var price = $('#filter').val();

    $('tr').show();

    $('tr td.price').each(function() {
        if ($(this).text().substring(1) < price)
        {
            $(this).parent().hide();
        }
    });

});
```

This code is a basic way of filtering it. The substring(1) removes the £ from the price. It hides all rows that have a price less than what you enter. I hope you can adapt it to solve your problem:)

Comment: Just making a JSFiddle and was thinking the same thing! http://jsfiddle.net/fKn2u/10/

Comment: Thanks will try out! p.s Can it be max price?

Comment: I've fixed your code: http://jsfiddle.net/fKn2u/16/ - just added the substring to remove the £ and fixed a missing close bracket after your inner function :)

Comment: Just change the < around or add your own logic to change how it filters :)

Comment: I have successfully added this example o my table and added a slider, however if you go below 10 all the rows that include the single digit still appear?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#input").on("keyup",function(){
        value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        $("#table tr").filter(function(){
            $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
        })

    })
})
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).